# PyCharm: How to view model dependency diagram in UML for SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, uml, flask-sqlalchemy

How to view model dependency diagram for SQLAlchemy in PyCharm?

I'm trying to follow the steps from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-model-dependency-diagram.html but only classes inheritance is showed.

What I want is models' relationships like Many-to-Many etc like in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2019.2/rm_diagram_model_example.png

I use PyCharm **2019.1.3** Professional Edition.

Any tips will be appreciated.